# How to open write reserved excel file in python with win32com?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I'm trying to open a write-protected ms excel 2007 file using win32com in python -- I know the password.  I can open it with user input of the password into the excel dialog box.  I want to be able to open the file without any user interaction.  I've tried the following, but it still pops up the dialog box.

```
app.Workbooks.Open("filename.xls", WriteResPassword="secret")
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong please?

Thanks,

Dave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can get the above code to work if I don't try to use named function parameters.  I.e. the following works:

```
app.Workbooks.Open("filename.xls", 2, True, None, None, "secret")
```