# Edit read-only password protected excel with Python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to find a way to edit a password protected excel with Python. Password is not required to open the excel, it is only required if you want to edit it:

[image]

Is it possible to access this using password and edit it? Would be perfect if it would be possible to edit it using Openpyxl. I have already tried to use msoffcrypto:

```
decrypted = io.BytesIO()

with open("encrypted.xlsx", "rb") as f:
    file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(f)
    file.load_key(password="Passw0rd")  # Use password
    file.decrypt(decrypted)

df = pd.read_excel(decrypted)
```

But I think this works only when you can access the file only with password (the whole file is password encrypted, not the edit part.

Comment: With Xlwings yes, see here for the options https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71267540/xlwings-open-password-protected-worksheet-in-xlsx

Comment: Did you try your code, any error output you can share?

Comment: @hc_dev - yes, I receive following error: "Unencrypted document or unsupported file format".

Answer (score 0):

If the Excel workbook has been [saved with a "Password to modify" like in Office 2011](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/require-a-password-to-open-or-modify-a-workbook-10579f0e-b2d9-4c05-b9f8-4109a6bce643#ID0EBBF=Office_2011) then you you usually need to perform following steps in Excel to save an unprotected version:

1. enter the password
2. open the workbook (still it is write-protected)
3. save as (unprotected)

#### In Python

You can decrypt it using a password and then pass the decrypted byte stream - as file-like object - to the opening function, be it `pandas.read_excel()` or `openpyxl.load_workbook()`:

```
import io

import msoffcrypto
import openpyxl


decrypted_workbook = io.BytesIO()

with open('encrypted.xlsx', 'rb') as file:
    office_file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(file)
    office_file.load_key(password='passw0rd')
    office_file.decrypt(decrypted_workbook)

# `filename` can also be a file-like object.
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=decrypted_workbook)
```

See also:

- [Reading encrypted file with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71678209/reading-encrypted-file-with-pandas)
- [How to open a password protected excel file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450837/how-to-open-a-password-protected-excel-file-using-python)
- [how to read password protected excel in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783980/how-to-read-password-protected-excel-in-python/3784019#3784019)

Comment: Sadly, none of these are able to modify a read-only password protected document (it is not considered as encrypted as I understand) since it can be opened like any other unencrypted document, the only difference that if you want to modify it you need to enter a password.