# How can i create a excel xlsx file with required password when open in Linux using Python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, pyspark, encryption

I have a dataframe.
I need to write dataframe to excel file with password required when open it.
On Linux environment.
How can i do that?

I try some packages like msoffcrypto, but it just can decrypt. encrypt feature is EXPERIMENT, cann't use now.
pywin32 and xlings just available on Win or Mac, so cann't use too.
I stucked. Help me

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/75069675/12846804

Comment: Is it a new Workbook you want to create or an existing Workbook that you are writing the DF to? If the later is it already protected?

Comment: @OCa Nah, I want encrypted file.

Comment: @moken i want create new file.For example, i have df_data with 10 rows. I want create new excel file from df_data requiment password when open.

Comment: Xlwings/Win32com use Excel so wont work on Linux. Openpyxl will work on Linux since it edits the underlying xml files, doesn't use Excel at all. However Openpyxl does not now and probably never will support Excel workbook password protection. It only supports Sheet protection. However as an XLSX file is just a bunch of ZIPed files you can use standard ZIP utilities to zip these files with standard ZIP encryption. However you would need to use ZIP to unzip/re-zip as un-encrypted zipped file before using as neither Excel or Openpyxl would be able to open it with the ZIP encryption.

Comment: There are other modules like Spire.XLS and Aspose-cells which claim to work on Linux and offer workbook encryption. However these are modules that provide a trial period before requiring payment for ongoing use so are not so popular. I've not used them so cannot verify these will fulil your requirement.

Comment: Does this help? https://medium.com/@alice.yang_10652/7-ways-to-protect-or-encrypt-excel-files-in-python-5a01a8e55c9e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encryption capabilities of `msoffcrypto` are indeed labeled as experimental, but as of the latest version (v.5.3.1), they are already usable.

It is a third-party tool, however, so no guarantees can be provided regarding its use.

- https://github.com/nolze/msoffcrypto-tool?tab=readme-ov-file#encryption-ooxml-only-experimental

CLI:

```bash
msoffcrypto-tool -e -p Passw0rd plain.xlsx encrypted.xlsx
```

Python code:

```py
import msoffcrypto

file_path = "encrypted.xlsx"
password = "Passw0rd"
decrypted_file_path = "decrypted.xlsx"

with open(file_path, "rb") as encrypted:
    file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(encrypted)
    file.load_key(password=password)  # Load the encryption key (password)
    with open(decrypted_file_path, "wb") as decrypted:
        file.decrypt(decrypted)
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of `msoffcrypto`.