# How to open a password protected excel file using python?

Tags: python, excel, file-io, passwords, protected

I looked at the previous threads regarding this topic, but they have not helped solve the problem.

- [how to read password protected excel in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783980/how-to-read-password-protected-excel-in-python)
- [How to open write reserved excel file in python with win32com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887339/how-to-open-write-reserved-excel-file-in-python-with-win32com)

I'm trying to open a password protected file in excel without any user interaction.  I searched online, and found this code which uses win32com.client
When I run this, I still get the prompt to enter the password...

```
from xlrd import *
import win32com.client
import csv
import sys

xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
print "Excel library version:", xlApp.Version
filename,password = r"\\HRA\Myfile.xlsx", 'caa team'
xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename, Password=password)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't think that named parameters work in this case. So you'd have to do something like:

```
xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename, False, True, None, password)
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx for details on the Workbooks.Open method.

Answer (score 30):

I recently discovered a Python library that makes this task simple.

It does not require Excel to be installed and, because it's pure Python, it's cross-platform too!

[msoffcrypto-tool](https://github.com/nolze/msoffcrypto-tool) supports password-protected (encrypted) Microsoft Office documents, including the older XLS binary file format.

- Install msoffcrypto-tool:

  ```
   pip install msoffcrypto-tool
  ```
- You could create an unencrypted version of the workbook from the command line:

  ```
  msoffcrypto-tool Myfile.xlsx Myfile-decrypted.xlsx -p "caa team"
  ```
- Or, you could use msoffcrypto-tool as a library. While you *could* write an unencrypted version to disk like above, you may prefer to create an decrypted in-memory file and pass this to your Python Excel library (`openpyxl`, `xlrd`, etc.).

  ```
  import io

  import msoffcrypto
  import openpyxl


  decrypted_workbook = io.BytesIO()

  with open('Myfile.xlsx', 'rb') as file:
      office_file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(file)
      office_file.load_key(password='caa team')
      office_file.decrypt(decrypted_workbook)

  # `filename` can also be a file-like object.
  workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=decrypted_workbook)
  ```

Comment: I cannot upvote this solution enough. Unlike various other solutions (such as using xlwings), this method allows you to read the decrypted data with the library you're already using, e.g. `pandas.read_excel(decrypted_workbook)` or `openpyxl.load_workbook(decrypted_workbook)`

Answer (score 1):

If your file size is small, you can probably save that as ".csv". 
and then read

It worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Openpyxl Package works if you are using linux system. You can use secure the file by setting up a password and open the file using the same password.

For more info:
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-open-read-password-protected-xls-or-xlsx-Excel-file-using-python-in-Linux

Comment: No, this doesn't work. I looked and found that Openpyxl cannot open a password-protected Excel.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you so much for the great answers on this topic. Trying to collate all of it. My requirement was to open a bunch of password protected excel files ( all had same password ) so that I could do some more processing on those. Please find the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

from xlrd import *
import win32com.client as w3c
import csv
import sys
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

    df_list=[]
#    print(len(files))
    for f in files:
#    print(f)
    if('.xlsx' in f):


        xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open('C:\\users\\files\\'+f, False, True, None, 'password')

        temp_f = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.csv')  
        temp_f.close()
        os.unlink(temp_f.name)  

        xlwb.SaveAs(Filename=temp_f.name, FileFormat=xlCSVWindows) 
        df = pd.read_csv(temp_f.name,encoding='Latin-1')  # Read that CSV from Pandas
        df.to_excel('C:\\users\\files\\password_removed\\'+f)
```

Comment: FYI this doesn't work as is, you gotta set xlapp as you did originally