# Working with Password Protected Excel Sheets in Python on Linux

Tags: python, linux, import-from-excel

The problem is pretty simple. Every week I receive a bunch of password protected excel files. I have to parse through them and write certain parts to a new file using Python. I am given the password for the files.

This was simple to handle when this was being done on Windows and I could just import win32com and use client.Dispatch. But we are now moving all our code to linux so no more win32com for me.

Is there a way to open and read data from a password protected excel sheet in python on linux?

I have been searching for simple way to open a password protected excel file but no luck. I also tried finding a way to just remove the password protection so I can use xlrd like I would on a file that is not password protected but no luck going that route either.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: This looks like it could work for you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450837/how-to-open-a-password-protected-excel-file-using-python

Comment: @perfectvid2012: No it doesn't. The whole point is to find a solution that does NOT use win32com (or anything else Windows-specific).

Comment: Hmm? Now I am confused.

Comment: I have no options to undelete anything. All I see is the one answer that is marked as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with `libreoffice` and `unoconv`

```
unoconv --password='p4ssw0rd' -f csv  protectedFile.xls
```

and then parse the `csv` file. Or export to another xls if you need the formatting or want to torture yourself

N.B. Edited after accepted. (`--password` is the correct switch, not `-p`, as noted by @enharmonic)

I've recently had an easier time using [`xlsxunpass`](https://github.com/WillForan/xlsxunpass)

```
java -jar ./xlsxunpass.jar protected.xlsx unprotected.xlsx 'p4ssw0rd'
```

Comment: What if my .xlsx have multiple sheets

Comment: try writing to another format supporting sheets. e.g. `unoconv -p p4ssw0rd -f xlsx  protectedFile.xls`

Comment: doesn't run (with error)? or is still password protected? if you already have xlsx, try going to xls `unoconv -p p4ssw0rd -f xls protectedFile.xlsx` or ods `unoconv -p p4ssw0rd -f ods protectedFile.xlsx`

Comment: I'm getting this error 'Error: Unable to connect or start own listener. Aborting.' .  Any idea why?

Comment: @Raj I don't think the `-p` option is for passwords; docs say it is for specifying a port. "-p, --port
Port to listen on (as listener) or to connect to (as client).
Default port is '2002'."  https://linux.die.net/man/1/unoconv

Comment: @enharmonic i updated the answer. I wonder if this was a change in the command switches or if the answer never actually worked

Comment: @Will I can unlock the protected file using xlsxunpass package but not unoconv. I'm still getting the same error using unoconv.

Comment: xlsxunpass is the only thing that has worked for me so far; thanks for your work on it, @Will!