# Open password protected excel and find last row and read till that|| Python

Tags: python, excel

[SO POST LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450837/how-to-open-a-password-protected-excel-file-using-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

With reference from above content am able to open a password protected excel, but i have a requirement to read the excel data as well with the password protected excel that is opened. We cant use the method openpyxl.load_workbook('sample.xlsx') as again it prompts error when opening a password protected file, is there any other method to read the excel as a continuation of the shared link.