# How to open password protected Excel file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this code that I got from here:

[How to open a password protected excel file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450837/how-to-open-a-password-protected-excel-file-using-python)

```
from xlrd import *
import win32com.client
import csv
import sys

xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
print('Excel Library Version:', xlApp.Version)
xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(r'Y:\Production\Production Planning\Production Thruput\% of Completion.xlsm', False, True, None, 'pass2016')
```

However, it's not working for me.  I do not get an error, and the screen even shows the downloading dialog box (screenshot shown below) like if it's about to open my file... and then nothing.  What am I doing wrong?  I've been researching this for 2 hours and can't seem to find any answers that work for me

[image]

Comment: Try something like this other Stack Overflow article maybe
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450837/how-to-open-a-password-protected-excel-file-using-python

Comment: That's the page I'm referencing