# Opening a password protected file with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel

Firstly, I am a bit of a newbie on Python but I am trying to open this password-protected file that I've had for a while and it comes up with an error 'Exception has occured:BadZipFile.'

Here is the code.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook 

dir_file_path = './Copy of AA Listing - FB  06.09.2016 Rev L.xlsx'

workbook = load_workbook(dir_file_path)

workbook.security.lockStructure = False

workbook.save(dir_file_path)
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think openpyxl does not support opening password-protected excel files. Read answer to the following question it might help.
[How to open a password protected excel file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450837/how-to-open-a-password-protected-excel-file-using-python)