# How to password-protect an XLSX file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, xlsx, password-protection

I want to create an excel file with some data and password-protect the **entire** file, not just worksheets.
I've looked around many places but I haven't found a way without paid libraries like spire.xls package.
I couldn't install it for obscure reasons. I'm new in Python so those errors are beyond me.
I found that [here](https://medium.com/@alice.yang_10652/7-ways-to-protect-or-encrypt-excel-files-in-python-5a01a8e55c9e).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a password protected excel file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450837/how-to-open-a-password-protected-excel-file-using-python) (literally the first result on ddg)

Comment: Hi, Tranbi. I edited the question, thanks for commenting.

Comment: Please add any relevant code of your attempts inside the question. "*those errors are beyond me*" - You should also add the relevant errors (as text) - [ask]

Comment: @Camilo how doesn't msoffcrypto achieve exactly what you want? Have you look at it at all? https://github.com/nolze/msoffcrypto-tool?tab=readme-ov-file#encryption-ooxml-only-experimental-1

Comment: Tranbi, thank you, that works. I found another way also using xlwings:
xw.Book(r''+EXCEL_FILENAME)
wbb.save(password=EXCEL_FILE_PASSWORD, path=r''+EXCEL_FILENAME)
wbb.close()
The only thing is that if you have SensitivityLabel because of your organisation, the file opens up and asks you to set the label like public, private, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I got it. Thanks to the people in the comments.
What I wanted was to create a file and copy it on some SMB server. The file is XLSX, needs a password to be opened and a sensitivity label.

But as far as this question goes, to password-protect it, I created the file with xlswriter, created a plain handler, then opened an OOXMLFile with the previous handler, encrypted it (which means add a pwd to open it) then closed the original plain file:

```
import xlsxwriter
from msoffcrypto.format.ooxml import OOXMLFile

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(INTERMEDIATE_EXCEL_FILE)
ws = wb.add_worksheet()
ws.write_row('A1', FIELD_NAMES, cell_format=None)
r, c = 1, 0
for row in records:
    ws.write_row(r, c, row)
    r = r + 1
wb.close()
plain = open(INTERMEDIATE_EXCEL_FILE, "rb")
file = OOXMLFile(plain)
with open(EXCEL_FILENAME, "wb") as f:
    file.encrypt(EXCEL_FILE_PASSWORD, f)
plain.close()
```

I also achieved it with xlwings but it was opening the file asking me for manual setup of the sensitivity label, which is why I ended up using openpyxl to add the label. I smbclient.shutil to copy the file to the shared drive.